# android - how to change the color of settings button?

Tags: android, button, settings

The settings button right corner, it became not visible when I applied dark theme on Action Bar. How do I change its color so that it becomes visible? I'm guessing I have to mess with main.xml

```
android:color="..."
```

does not work

[image: aaa]

(this picture's brightness has been increased, normally it is really not visible)

Answer (score 0):

try this in onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method....

```
 menu.findItem(R.id.your_icon).setVisible(true);
```